# How to delete bluetooth devices paired with previous bluetooth dongle

Tags: usb, bluetooth

I had a bluetooth dongle. I paired a lot of devices to that Bluetooth dongle. That dongle. When I was moving the comp the dongle hit stuffs and got bent.

That is fine. I just replace the dongle. However, when I tried to remove previously connected devices I got a message remove failed

I just want to remove all registered Bluetooth devices from my computer. Reset and start a new.

[image]

So basically removing devices no longer work. It just stays there saying removing, eventually, it will briefly change the word removing device to remove failed and that's it.

How do I just scrap all paired devices from my computer?

Answer (score 1):

How >I< might do it is to go to the registry and delete them directly.

1. open RegEdit.exe
2. Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\BTHPORT\Parameters\Devices`
3. Select `File`->`Export` and backup the devices keys or right click the key and select `Export`. (I myself am a ***DareDevil*** and skip this step)
4. All of your devices are listed here by wacky hex keys.  If you REALLY want to know what each one is, click on the key, then double click the hex values under `Name`.. you will see the funkified ASCII name of the device on the right.
5. After cleaning up what you will.. reboot windows.

Remember, backup your crud often.  You never know when it might break. :^P

Edit:  You have a lot of points.. the previous reminder is for anyone ELSE following this guide.

Comment: I did that. Still there.

Comment: Not working I think someone have asked a similar question.

Answer (score 1):

I go to device manager

Then click view->show hidden devices

Then go to this area and delete your devices. I also delete the Bluetooth controller or something. Delete a lot. Destroy purge this area.

[image]

I checked back and all the bad devices are gone

[image]

Comment: This worked for me. Actually I just need to uninstall the old donge and all the devices related to it in the list are gone as well